# Windows App Certification Kit "The selection criteria did not match any tests"

Tags: desktop-bridge

I am preparing my app for upload to the MS Store and am running into problems with the Windows App Certification Kit. Nearly every test performed by the kit produces the exact same FAILED test result as follows:

"The selection criteria did not match any tests.
No test cases were executed."

My app is a Windows Forms app that was packaged using the "Windows Application Packaging Project" in Visual Studio 2017 (i.e. using the latest iteration of the MS "Desktop Bridge").

I should also add that I was able to successfully install the app bundle (.appxbundle) by loading the temporary cert and double clicking on the appxbundle so I know the UWP install works perfectly.

Any ideas on how to fix issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem! It appeared to me based upon the test result text that the Windows App Certification Kit was simply failing to run any tests at all...so I decided to uninstall then reinstall the Windows Software Development Kit (which includes the Windows App Cert Kit among other things). After reinstall the Windows App Cert Kit ran correctly!...AND MY APP PASSED EVERY SINGLE TEST!!! YES!!!

Anyhow, if you experience the same problem as me, you now have the solution to your issue...uninstall then reinstall the Windows Software Development Kit.